# What does # stand for in c++ code?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

What does the # before s mean in the following snippet? I am not referring to the # before define or the ones used for preprocessor directives.

```
// Quote a given token stream to turn it into a string.
#define DEV_QUOTED_HELPER(s) #s
#define DEV_QUOTED(s) DEV_QUOTED_HELPER(s)
```

This question is different from "Stringification - how does it work?" because someone having this question doesn't know the term 'stringification'. It is different from "What is '#' operator in C?" because it appears in C++ code too and in such cases even SO fails to show this question in the list of similar questions(it showed other possible questions in SQL, python etc).

Comment: Lookup the _stringizing_ macro operator. @MichaelO. No.

Comment: I guess should be tag c and neither c++ not c++11, this is c preprocessor directives

Comment: Okay @mpromonet. I had seen this snippet in a primarily c++ codebase.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor:

> The # operator (known as the "Stringification Operator") converts a
>   token into a string, escaping any quotes or backslashes appropriately.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> #define str(s) #s
>
> str(p = "foo\n";) // outputs "p = \"foo\\n\";"
> str(\n)           // outputs "\n"
> ```